# Prove that $e^x-x\geq 1$.

Tags: calculus

Please prove that
$$e^x - x$$ is always bigger than or equal to 1

Comment: Do you know calculus?

Answer (score 0):

We know that at $x-0$, $e^x-x=1$. The derivative is $e^x-1$, which for $x>0$, is positive, so $e^x-x$ starts at $1$, and then only increases from there. For $x<0$, $e^x-1$ is negative, so it is increasing as $x$ get more negative too. Thus, $e^x-x\geq1$.